# How to change qemu-kvm version on Eucalyptus cloud-in-a-box?

Tags: qemu, eucalyptus

I am trying to use libvmi tool on KVM virtual machine running on Eucalyptus cloud. It is a cloud-in-a-box 3.4.2 version. To use libvmi on KVM, it requires me to change the qemu-kvm that Eucalyptus by default uses. So I did a patch to the qemu-kvm-1.2.0 source code, compiled it and "make && make install" as this web page said: https://github.com/bdpayne/libvmi/tree/master/tools/qemu-kvm-patch.

Now I need to make sure my system will use this newly installed version of qemu-kvm when running KVM virtual machines. Could anyone tell me how to setup so that Eucalyptus would use my newly-installed qemu-kvm when launching new instances?

I tried "yum erase qemu-kvm", hoping to erase the original version of qemu-kvm so that maybe Eucalyptus would have to use the qemu I just compiled and installed. However when I used "yum erase qemu-kvm", it said "eucalyptus-nc" would also need to be erased for depedency reason, so I didn't continue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: This question doesn't seem programming related and would be more suited for serverfault.com

Comment: Well, it *is* about compiling a custom version of something and deploying it on top of a packaged version. Not a programming question, technically, but something of interest primarily to developers (and adventurous admins, perhaps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a couple options:

- Tell `configure` to install into location used by the packaged installation (perhaps something like `./configure --prefix=/`).
- Find the `qemu-kvm` binary on the system and overwrite it with the binary produced in the source tree during compilation.

A backup may help, but then you can always reinstall from packages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The newer version of qemu that I compiled from source even had a totally different name for the executable file (qemu-system-x86_64 instead of qemu-kvm) and different number of libs and bins. I ended up using the second method, back up the original files, and use the newer ones to replace the old ones as many as possible. It seems the newer version works now. Hope everything is fine. Thanks. :)